# creating a login page with HTML and php

Tags: php, html

I want to create create a login where a user can sign up for a site and then they are able to log in. I was the details to be added to a data in phpmyadim and when the users logs in I want the details to be got from the database. I already know how to do this but what I want to know is how do I get it that when the users logs in it takes them back to the homepage and the right hand conner it says "hello emma" (or whoever is logged in)

Here is my code so far

main login

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Buzz Party | Login</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        </head>


<body> 
     
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
    
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

login success

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Reguster

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black" style="color:white;">
<FORM ACTION="register.php" METHOD=get>
<h1>welcome to the registration page</h1>
please input the registration details to create an account here<br>
<table border="2">
<tr>
<td>User Name :</td><td><input name="regname" type="text" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>email :</td><td><input name="regemail" type="text" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>password :</td><td><input name="regpass1" type="password" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>retype password :</td><td><input name="regpass2" type="password" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="register me!"></input>
</FORM>

<?php
if($_GET["regname"] && $_GET["regemail"] && $_GET["regpass1"] && $_GET["regpass2"] )
{
if($_GET["regpass1"]==$_GET["regpass2"])
{

$host="localhost";
$username="root"; 
$password="root";
$conn= mysql_connect($hot,$username, $password)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("login",$conn);
$sql="insert into users (name,email,password)values('$_GET[regname]','$_GET[regemail]','$_GET[regpass1]')";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
print "<h1>you have registered sucessfully</h1>";

print "<a href='index.html'>go to login page</a>";
}
else print "passwords doesnt match";
}
else print"invaild data";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? I don't see `echo "Hello " . $_SESSION['username'];` anywhere.

Comment: no I didn't think to try that

Comment: can I put that on a page with HTML and php that doesn't have any login php code?

Comment: You are really Omnipresent, right @Fred-ii- ? LOL... Every post you comment something. =)

Comment: The trick is, to assign a session variable to something; whether it's a POST array or GET. Then check if it's set and echoing the session's array anywhere in pages that are using sessions.

Comment: @bcesars I enjoy helping out ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-. EAH. Its kind of funny. I wanna learn with you... =)

Comment: @bcesars Be sure to have a lungo or double shot of *Espresso*. With me, it's *go-go-go!* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

it looks as though you are already redirecting the authenticated user to a homepage.

All you need to do is add a [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) variable which contains their name, and then spit it out when you need it.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username; // from your database of users
```

then you can echo it into some html.

```
<div id='welcome'>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
            echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username']; 
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

remember you need to have `session_start();` at the top of every page. And that the page needs to have a .php extension.

**edit**

as you have said, you are having trouble redirecting the user.  if you are using php v5.4+ `session_is_registered` has been removed.

You should use `isset($_SESSION['username'])` instead in your if statement.  But as also said in comments, you have a rogue `session_destroy` in your page which will end your session right after you start it.  This `session_start` also must be the first thing in your page. At the moment you have it under some html output.

Comment: This **could** work... maybe after he deletes that `session_destroy();` from his main login ;)

Comment: I am having a problem that when the user is logged in I cant get it to take them back to the homepage (index page)